# Argument type {path: string, component HomeComponent}[] is not assignable to parameter type Routes

Tags: angular

Trying to set up routing for the first time on Angular 2 (router 3.0.0)

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { RouterModule} from '@angular/router';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { BoardComponent } from './board/board.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    BoardComponent,
    HomeComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot([
        { path: '', component: HomeComponent }
    ])
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

I get the error:

```
Argument type {path: string, component HomeComponent}[] is not assignable to parameter type Routes
```

Not sure what's going on here as I'm following the docs almost to the letter: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html.

Edit: `home.component.ts`:

```
<p>Home works!</p>
```

Comment: Please show code of `home.component.ts`

Comment: Please add all your code from `home.component.ts`. `HomeComponent`should be a class with `@Component` decorator

Answer (score 0):

You can fix this, by change your `HomeComponent` a little bit.
It should extends `Type` from `@angular/core`. And don't forget `super` method!

Something like that:

```
import { Component, Type } from '@angular/core'; 

@Component({...}) 
export class HomeComponent extends Type { 
  constructor() { 
    super(); 
  } 
  ... 
}
```